# Android onDraw called a large number of times

Tags: android

In the following snippet the `onDraw` method is called around 10-15 times. Can anyone explain this behaviour

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        View v = new View(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("large view on draw called");
                super.onDraw(canvas);
            }
        };
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2000));
        LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll2.addView(v);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        sv.addView(ll2);
        ll.addView(sv);
        LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll1.addView(ll);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you do something that might affect a widget, the widget will be redrawn. Putting the widget in a container might affect it. Putting the container in another container might affect it.

You should be making no assumptions about how many times `onDraw()` will be called, other than that it will be called a lot and therefore needs to be fast.

Comment: Actually if I don't follow the above hierarchy then the final view does not seem to provide a scrollable view. Besides the 10-15 times onDraw call occurs even when the view is being rendered the first time. Is there any way to optimize the above layout.